# jquery wrapAll function inverse?

Tags: jquery

jquery has a function `.wrapAll()` which is used to wrap around all divs with same class.

but I want to do exactly inverse of this means unwrap multiple divs with same class in single go as there is no `unwrapAll()` function there??
Is it possible to do???

E.g. Before

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">foon</div>
<div class="inner">foon2</div>
<div class="inner">foo3</div>    
</div>​
```

after:

```
<div class="inner">foon</div>
<div class="inner">foon2</div>
<div class="inner">foo3</div>
```

**Working example using suggested answer** : http://jsfiddle.net/ScdLX/4/

Comment: Everything is possible in jQuery. Can you show a before/after example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$(".outerDiv").replaceWith(function () { return $(this).html(); });
```

That does not remove text node children of `.outerDiv`, though.

http://jsfiddle.net/ScdLX/2/

EDIT: per @NullPointer you can do this using the `.unwrap` method on the children of the parent selector.  Please see:

http://jsfiddle.net/ScdLX/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use like .

```
jQuery('.classname').children().unwrap();
```

that remove all the element with class name "classname"

Comment: i am afraid that this same is in the Explosion pills [second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ScdLX/3/)

Comment: At 1st preference I tried .unwrap() but It did'nt worked in my case. Actually I have dynamic data loaded on click and every time I click a new div created with same class. I have to remove wrap from all such divs with same class and add wrap again live. Anyway thanks for answer.